# css border around multiple links/images

Tags: html, css

I have 4 images which are links, I want to create a border but instead of creating it around each image (which automatically CSS does) I want to create it around the 4 images as a whole.

Comment: wrap the all 4 images inside a `div` and than apply `border` to `div`

Answer (score 4):

Place the images in a div and then make the border on the div
something like this:

```
<style>
.image-div{
 border:1px #000;
}
</style>
<div class="image-div">
  <img src="">
  <img src="">
  <img src="">
  <img src="">
</div>
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you, I must have been having a blank....

Comment: if it solved your problem please mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RXmb9/4/

Wrap your images in a span or a div and then apply the border.

**CSS**

```
.cool { border:1px solid red; }
 img { width:50px; height:50px; }
 .one { /* Apply specific borders for images if you want */ }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="cool">
  <img src="" class="one" />
  <img src="" class="two" />
  <img src="" class="three" />
  <img src="" class="four" />
</div>
```